# Load Json data into nvd3 graph

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm stuck with a problem that seems so easy to solve. I just can't make it work - there must be a stupid mistake somewhere which I can't find. Maybe some other eyes can find what is wrong?

I try to load a json data file into a nvd3 graph but it does not work.

There is no problem when hardcoding the data but as soon as I try to get the same data from an external file, it doesn't work.

Working version with hardcoded data: http://jsfiddle.net/Marei/1azqmx1L/14/

**Non** working version with external file: http://jsfiddle.net/Marei/38e53cz0/

```
d3.json('http://www.kato-media.de/transfer/data.json', function(data) {
nv.addGraph(function() {


var maxY = d3.max(d3.merge(data.map(function(d){return d.values})),
 function(d) {return d.rank});


var chart = nv.models.lineChart()

  .x(function(d) {return d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse(d.date) })
  .y(function(d) {return d.rank})


  .yDomain([maxY+1,0])  //Inverts y-axis 


  .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
  .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
  .margin({left: 100})
  .margin({right: 50})
  .margin({bottom: 100}) 

    ;


 chart.options({
           noData: "Not enough data to graph",
            rightAlignYAxis: false,
    });


//Map all xValues for each dataset to an array (tmp) --- To make sure all x-axis ticks have a label
var tmp = data.map(function(e) {
return e.values.map(function(d) {
    return d3.time.format('%Y%m%d').parse(d.date);
});
});

//And flatten out that array, so you have all your xValues in a 1D-array
var xValues = [].concat.apply([], tmp);


chart.legend.margin({top: 10, right:60, left:80, bottom: 50});


chart.xAxis
  .tickFormat(function(d) {return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(d)) })
    .rotateLabels(-45)
    .tickValues(xValues)
     .showMaxMin(false)
  ;



 chart.xScale(d3.time.scale()); //fixes misalignment of timescale with line graph

  chart.yAxis
    .axisLabel('Rank')
    .tickFormat(d3.format('d'))
    .showMaxMin(true)
    .tickPadding(10);

  ;



  d3.select('#chart svg')
.datum(data)
.transition().duration(500)
.call(chart)
;

 nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
```

Link to my json file: http://www.kato-media.de/transfer/data.json

Maybe someone has a minute to look at my code and help me out. Thank you some much for your time!

Comment: Do you get this file from an API or is a simple local file?

Comment: @Giordano At the moment I would be happy if I can make it work with a local file. Once that is done, I will try to get the data from a database via php without a  file in between. Sorry, it's my first try with nvd3/d3 and I'm not very familiar with js ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first suggestion I'd make is to include error checking on the json call and add a console.log for the read data, then you will know if d3.json did the trick for you. For example:

```
d3.json('http://www.kato-media.de/transfer/data.json', function(error, data) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);
  console.log(data);
```

The second is to revise your json file, at first sight it seems to me that *date* and *rank* should be under quotes but there could be another errors as well.

Use a json online parser to check your file out, sometimes I use http://json.parser.online.fr/ but your mileage may vary. Anyway, it is easy to find other json online parsers though.

Just checked your json. If you enclose all data and rank into quotes and take out ending commas at lines 20, 43, 64, 85 and 87 you will be able to read data.json.
Also your fiddle is missing the closing "};" for the d3.json call.

Comment: Just checked your json. If you enclose all data and rank into quotes and take out ending commas at lines 20, 43, 64, 85 and 87 you will be able to read data.json.

Also, as @Giordano said, your fiddle is missing the closing }; for the d3.json call.

Comment: Thank you. I have cleaned up my json file but still can't make it work. Updated fiddle: jsfiddle.net/Marei/b1xq8xa0/3 with new (cleaned up file) data-new.json

Comment: I've made it work with the suggested changes on my localhost, will check your fiddle out. Did you see any console messages after d3.json ?

Comment: By the way, here is the corrected json file I'm using: http://stelling.cc/data.json  It is simply your original file with the suggested corrections.

Comment: That's great! If that did the trick then please feel free to mark my answer as useful... ;) I'm a new user in here and will very well appreciate the additional reputation score.

Comment: Follow up question: It's all working fine with your file when using the local file d3.json('data-new.json', function(error, data) { .. but as soon as I put the same file online and try to load it, it does not work: d3.json('http://www.kato-media.de/transfer/data-new.json', function(error, data) { ... Anything I can do?

Comment: It the file on the same server where your application is running ? Then simply put a local reference to the file on the json call (./transfer/data-new.json, for example).

Comment: okay, so far so good. With the html and the json on the server, it is working. You have been so helpful, is it okay if I ask you another question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100986/discussion-between-roberto-stelling-and-marei).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest you to correct your json; if you check with a online tools like this http://jsonlint.com/ you can see that there are some errors.

For example you can change this:

```
{
    date: "20151221",
    rank: "1"
}
```

in this:

```
{
    "date": "20151221",
    "rank": "1"
}
```

I checked your second fiddle that you have posted, and there is an error; missing another });.

Look at this, I update you fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b1xq8xa0/

For include a local file you instruction is correct:

```
d3.json('your file.json', function(data){
```

Comment: Thank you! I have done what you said and cleaned up my json file, still I can't make it work. What am I missing?  Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Marei/b1xq8xa0/3/  with new (cleaned up file) data-new.json

Comment: Did you try only on jsfiddle or also in real case?

Comment: No, I'm using a local html document. The fiddle was just to show you the code. I got it working, als longs as it's all local  d3.json('data-new.json', function(error, data) { .. but as soon as I put the same file online and try to load it, it does not work: d3.json('kato-media.de/transfer/data-new.json';, function(error, data) { ... Anything I can do?

Comment: As longs as the html and the json are running live, it's fine. Thank you for your great effort!